# How to set a default background image on swift

Tags: swift

I want a background image to all my views. I'm able to do this on my controller:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)
}
```

But I want this to be applied to all controllers, one solution was to create a common controller though I think there should be a better approach. I'm trying to set this on appDelegate

```
    self.window!.rootViewController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)
```

But no luck, any suggestions?

Comment: Your app delegate code will only work for the first view controller your app displays; once you navigate out of it, you will need to set the background again. Use either the subclassing approach or the extension approach listed in the answers given, depending on what suits you best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I could get is this extension

```
extension UIViewController {
    func colorMe() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)
    }
}
```

Now you just have to invoke `colorMe()` in each `ViewController` you want to color.

I know you still need to write a few code in each `ViewController` but at least you have a centralized definition of the color for your whole app.

Is that enough?

Comment: Thanks for reply, sounds a little better than have a common Controller. I'll take that as correct. But I'm still bothered, cause it seems to be an ordinary thing to do, there should be away to customize the app style much easier.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom ViewController that initializes with the background you want and every time you need a new ViewController, it will inherit from this other one you've created.

```
import UIKit

class SameBackgroundViewController: UIViewController {

var background: UIImageView!

init(imageName: String) {

    self.background = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName))
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.background.frame = self.view.frame

}

convenience init() {

    let imageName = "background.jpg"
    self.init(imageName: imageName)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(background)

}
}
```

And now the new view controller will be like this

```
class NewViewController: SameBackgroundViewController {

}
```

Hope I could help, this is my first answer on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thanks for reply @LeoWajnsztok  I initially had done a similar solution as you suggested, 

It was matter to override the viewDidLoad and set the background. But still I think the extension solution is a better way to go.